# How can I disable echo in terminal

Tags: cat, echo

This might seem simple but sometimes I need terminal to not echo anything ,
whether for a specific command or all commands.

in windows I could simply do `echo off`

I tend to make files with `cat` command a lot but it returns whatever I'm entering and I feel like an Alcoholic because I see double.

example :

```
cat | sudo tee -a vocab.txt

I am the first line
I am the first line
I am the second line
I am the second line
```

Comment: Possible solution could be to modify your command to "cat | sudo tee -a vocab.txt>/dev/null"

Comment: It worked but didn't make vocab.txt @JohnRonald

Comment: `tee -a filename` appends to the file.  `tee filename` creates the file.  And with what @JohnRonald posted above worked for me for creating a new file as well.  You may not need the `sudo` if you are not writing into a folder that is owned by root or not you.

Comment: Don't use `tee` if you don't want any [extra] output to the terminal. Simply redirect the output to where you want it, modify the command in your question to (as one single line) `cat > vocab.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn terminal echo off with the command:

```
stty -echo
```

(warning: after entering this command, you won't see following commands that you'll type)

and turn it on again with the command:

```
stty echo
```

Comment: Dude I might haven't been clear I don't want the terminal to respond to me but I want to see what I'm typing. I tried what you said but all it did was hiding what I'm typing . I want the exact opposite.

Comment: @YoloWex, you are the one who seeks help. Is this how you address those willing to help you?

Comment: @YoloWex So what's your problem then? Seeing what you type is a default setting, you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to run:

```
set +x
```

Turning on echo is

```
set -x
```

I just ran into this issue when a script failed and the terminal kept echo'ing all the commands I typed afterwards. This is the first answer than came up when I tried searching for a fix.

More info:

> set -x enables a mode of the shell where all executed commands are printed to the terminal. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do)

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

The option to switch echoing of the command in a terminal off - with bash as a shell is:

```
set +v

# - the -->  set -v <-- sets the command echoing back on
```